# Obtener option seleccionado dentro de un optgroup

Tags: javascript, html, select

Teniendo un select como este:

```
<select id="main">
   <optgroup label="Coches">
      <option value="Mustang">Mustang</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Motos">
      <option value="Scooter">Scooter</option>
      <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

estoy buscando la forma de obtener el value de la opción seleccionada por el usuario a través de JavaScript, tras muchas pruebas y búsqueda de información no doy con la acertada.
Por lo que sé, hay que tratar al optgroup como un objeto, y utilizando un índice se puede obtener la opción seleccionada, no?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: En la propia etiqueta HTML le estás indicando el `value` independientemente del valor que recoja del usuario tu siempre pondrías `value="Mustang"`

Comment: A la hora de obtener el valor, este se recoje de la opción seleccionada por el usuario, si este hace click sobre Extra, se obtendrá "Extra",como indica su correspondiente value, igual que si fuese Mustang.

Comment: Hice una prueba de tu código con el clásico selectedIndex, y me retornó el valor esperado: `obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value` ¿Cuáles formas has intentado que no te han funcionado como esperabas?

Comment: Gracias a todos. Por lo visto estaba utilizando los índices pero no buscaba el valor dentro del array correctamente..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí lo que deseas es el valor de la opción seleccionada por JavasScript es así:

```
var select = document.getElementById('main');
select.addEventListener('change',
function(){
var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
console.log(selectedOption.value + ': ' + selectedOption.text);
});
```

Y por JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').change(function () {            
       $("#main option:selected").each(function () {
            elegido=$(this).val();                                  
       });         
    });
});
```

o

```
$('#main').val()
```

Comment: la mejor opcion es jquery te ahorras codigo como muestra el comentario de arriba:  $('#main').val()

Comment: Esta respuesta me ha venido genial, con dos opciones por escojer, gracias, me funciona!

Comment: Exacto, una opción para obtenerlo cuando lo seleccionas y una poción para después de seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

Con JQuery puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

EDIT

Agregado código para obtener el label del `optgroup` también.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main").on("change",function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').attr('label'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="main">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
  <optgroup label="Coches">
   <option value="Mustang">Mustang</option>
   <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Motos">
   <option value="Scooter">Scooter</option>
   <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Se agradece la fácil explicación y directa ejecución de la respuesta en la web :D